# visual studio no asp.net possibility

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

so i just installed microsoft visual studio express 2012 for windows 8 (virtual machine) and i noticed there is no option of creating .asp files

normally, i should be able to file -> new web site, c#, empty. And then add a new web form to create an aspx file, but i dont get these options.

i only get file -> new project which creates javascript (javascript) or XAML files (visual basic, visual C#, visual C++)

i assume there is something wrong with installation. i tried installing ASP.NET from the asp.net website but doesnt change anything.

please hold in mind i am a beginner,
any help is much appreciated

Comment: You installed the version for creating Metro applications.  That's all it does.  You need to install the web version to do asp.net.

Comment: It sounds like you've got the wrong tool...shouldn't you be using the web edition? (It sounds like you got the desktop/app edition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this one; sounds like you downloaded the WPF version  http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-web

Answer (score 2):

You must install the web version to do `asp.net.`

Check this **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537667.aspx)**